# Core data many relations to the same model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, database-design

I noticed that each time when I create new relation between models it asks me to create inverse binding. But I faced with problem that I want create many relations to the same model. 
My `Core Data` scheme:

[image]

Now I should create relations from Color model and I need 2 relations according each relation from `House` model. How to avoid this? What is best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

With the model and the relationship selected, look in the right pane there is a dropdown named Type. Set that value to "To Many".

Answer (score 0):

Each relationship has its own reverse relationship. The Color entity should have two releationships, one for exteriorColors and one for interiorColors.